# Filtering data with keywords with a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I am trying to filter out data from a csv file and I am trying to organize it in a way that it looks like this

```
0 AIG,10,,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,
1 Baylor College of Medicine,19,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,,,Recent
2 CGG,17,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,MS,PhD,Recent
3 Citi,27/28,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
4 ExxonMobil,11,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
5 Flow-Cal Inc.,16,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,All
6 Global Shop Solutions,18,Yes,,,Yes,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
7 Harris County CTS,22,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
8 HCSS,29,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
9 Hitachi Consulting,13,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,,
10 HP Inc.,1,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,Recent
11 INT Inc.,20,Yes,Yes,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,MS,PhD,
12 JPMorgan Chase & Co,3,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
13 Leidos,390,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
14 McKesson,26,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,,,
15 MRE Consulting Ltd.,2,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,All
16 NetIQ,7,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
17 PROS,21,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,PhD,All
18 San Jacinto College ,14,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
19 SAS,4,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
20 Smartbridge,8,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
21 Sogeti USA,15,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
22 Southwest Research Institute,12,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
23 The Reynolds and Reynolds Company,23,Yes,Yes,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,All
24 UH Enterprise Systems,9,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
25 U.S. Marine Corps,25,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,All
26 ValuD Consuting LLC,5,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
27 Wipro,24,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,
```

However, my code is giving me this right now

```
0 AIG,10,,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,
1 Baylorï¿½Collegeï¿½ofï¿½Medicine,19,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,,,Recent
2 CGG,17,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,MS,PhD,Recent
3 Citi,27/28,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
4 ExxonMobil,11,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
5 HCSS,29,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
6 Leidos,390,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
7 McKesson,26,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,,,
8 NetIQ,7,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
9 PROS,21,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,PhD,All
10 SAS,4,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
11 Smartbridge,8,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
12 Wipro,24,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,
13 SAS,4,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
14 NetIQ,7,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
15 Smartbridge,8,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
16 AIG,10,,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,
17 ExxonMobil,11,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
18 CGG,17,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,MS,PhD,Recent
19 Baylorï¿½Collegeï¿½ofï¿½Medicine,19,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,,,Recent
20 PROS,21,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,PhD,All
21 Wipro,24,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,
22 McKesson,26,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,,,
23 Citi,27/28,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
24 HCSS,29,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
25 Leidos,30,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
```

As you can see it seems to repeat certain keywords I used which I will post my code below.

```
#I made a dictonary of the problem stated
company_dict = {0:"Company", 1:"Booth",
                2:"Full-Time", 3:"Full-Time Visa Sponsor",
                4:"Part-Time", 5:"Internship",
                6:"Freshman", 7:"Sophomore",
                8:"Junior", 9:"Senior",
                10:"Post-Bacs", 11:"MS",
                12:"PhD", 13:"Alumni"}

#Loop to organize the company_dict
for lines in company_dict:
    print(repr(lines),company_dict[lines])

keywords = ("AIG","Baylor","CGG","Citi","ExxonMobil","Flow-Cal Inc.",
           "Global SHop Solutions","Harris Count CTS","HCSS",
           "Hitachi Consulting", "HP Inc.","INT Inc.","JPMorgan Chase & Co",
           "Leidos","McKesson","MRE Consulting Ltd.","NetIQ","PROS",
           "San Jacinto College","SAS","Smartbridge","Sogeti USA",
           "Southwest Research Institute","The Reynolds and Reynolds Company",
           "UH Enterprise Systems","U.S. Marine Corps","ValuD Consuting LLC","Wipro")

with f as filterf:
    output_line_counter = 0
    for line in filterf:
        if any(keyword in line for keyword in keywords):
            print(output_line_counter, line.strip())
            output_line_counter += 1
```

This all comes from csv file that is included in the assignment. I think I am on the right track, but I do not understand why my code is giving me repeats, and also missing out on 'keywords' I asked for it to search for.

I will include the csv data below

```
ALPHABETICAL ORDER,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,Positions,,,,Classifications,,,,,,,
Company,Booth,Full-Time,"Full-Time Visa Sponsor",Part-Time,Internship,Freshman,Sophomore,Junior,Senior,Post-Bacs,MS,PhD,Alumni
AIG,10,,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,
Baylor�College�of�Medicine,19,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,,,Recent
CGG,17,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,MS,PhD,Recent
Citi,27/28,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
ExxonMobil,11,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
,...
Flow-Cal�Inc.,16,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,All
Global�Shop�Solutions,18,Yes,,,Yes,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
Harris�County�CTS,22,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
HCSS,29,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
Hitachi�Consulting,13,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,,
HP�Inc.,1,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,Recent
INT�Inc.,20,Yes,Yes,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,MS,PhD,
JPMorgan�Chase�&�Co,3,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
Leidos,390,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
McKesson,26,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,
MRE�Consulting�Ltd.,2,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,All
NetIQ,7,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
PROS,21,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,PhD,All
San�Jacinto�College��,14,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
SAS,4,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
Smartbridge,8,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
Sogeti�USA,15,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
Southwest�Research�Institute,12,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
The�Reynolds�and�Reynolds�Company,23,Yes,Yes,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,All
UH�Enterprise�Systems,9,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
U.S.�Marine�Corps,25,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,All
ValuD�Consuting�LLC,5,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
Wipro,24,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,
BOOTH ORDER,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Booth,Positions,,,,Classifications,,,,,,,
Company,#,Full-Time,"Full-Time
Visa Sponsor",Part-Time,Internship,Freshman,Sophomore,Junior,Senior,Post-Bacs,MS,PhD,Alumni
HP�Inc.,1,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,Recent
"MRE�Consulting,�Ltd.",2,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,All
JPMorgan�Chase�&�Co,3,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
SAS,4,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
ValuD�Consuting�LLC,5,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
NetIQ,7,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
Smartbridge,8,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
UH�Enterprise�Systems,9,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
AIG,10,,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,
ExxonMobil,11,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
Southwest�Research�Institute,12,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
Hitachi�Consulting,13,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,,
San�Jacinto�College��,14,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
Sogeti�USA,15,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
"Flow-Cal,�Inc.",16,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,All
CGG,17,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,MS,PhD,Recent
Global�Shop�Solutions,18,Yes,,,Yes,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
Baylor�College�of�Medicine,19,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,,,Recent
"INT,�Inc.",20,Yes,Yes,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,MS,PhD,
PROS,21,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,PhD,All
Harris�County�CTS,22,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
The�Reynolds�and�Reynolds�Company,23,Yes,Yes,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,All
Wipro,24,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,
U.S.�Marine�Corps,25,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,All
McKesson,26,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,,,
Citi,27/28,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
HCSS,29,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
Leidos,30,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
```

I think it has to do something with the question marks in the box from the csv file but I am not sure. I wanted to search the csv file from the keywords I gave it, and print that row. Thank you so much for any input or advice :)

Comment: your csv is broken. the questionmark represent characters that are not readable. try to get behind which encoding was used to write the csv and open it with that exact encoding - you wont be able to match your keywords to your data if your data is corrupt. it seems your ? in csv are spaces. copy csv, replace questionmark by spaces and run your program again with the modified file

Comment: Is their a way to write it where if it already has the keyword it won't write it again? I think that's why I keep getting duplicates when I print it

Comment: whenever you print one, add the keyword to a set. check the set if the keyword is in before you print. no duplicate keywords that way

Answer (score 0):

Answer was cvs file just needed to be changed (hope it's ok for the project it had weird UTF errors)

I also added to the following code

```
DataList = []
with f as filterf:
    output_line_counter = 0
    for line in filterf:
        if any(keyword in line for keyword in keywords):
            output_line_counter += 1
            DataList.append(line)

CleanerData = sorted(set(DataList))
line_counter = 0
for i in CleanerData:
    line_counter += 1
    print(line_counter, i, end='')
```